# why is the chain rule used for the area function $A=\frac{1}{2}xy$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

To differentiate the area of a triangle function, $A=\dfrac{1}{2}xy$ with respect to time $t$, my text says to use the chain rule and the product rule.

So it would be: $\dfrac{dA}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{2}(x\dfrac{dy}{dt}+y\dfrac{dx}{dt})$
Isn't this only the product rule? I don't see the chain rule here. Why do we have to use the chain rule here, because area is a function of $x$ and $y$ and $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$? Is that correct?

Thanks.

Comment: For functions involving just multiplication of other simple functions the chain rule and product rule are equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: here we only need the product rule. Since $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$ perhaps it would be clearer if we wrote them as $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. Then we have

$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{2}x(t)y(t)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}x(t)y(t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(x'(t)y(t)+y'(t)x(t)\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(y\frac{dx}{dt}+x\frac{dy}{dt}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the total derivative: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative)

$\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{dA}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dA}{dv}\cdot \frac{dy}{dt}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\cdot y \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot x \cdot \frac{dy}{dt}$

greetings,

calculus